# Does kivy has opencv or image processing library?

Tags: android, kivy

Does anyone know if kivy has image processing library?? I am planning to do android application project for one of my class but I do not know java. I have experience with c++ and python and I know there are some development tools for android app. I prefer to use python but c++ is also good. So anyone have information?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can easily do is to import numpy to your as usual, write your code accordingly. You can almost do any image processing with numpy, however it won't be accelerated...

Anyways, while building the Kivy application's apk file (I would advise you to use buildozer from github), just include it to your build. Here is an example of adding numpy to your apk build by adjusting specific line in buildozer.spec:

```html
requirements = kivy,numpy
```

As far as I know, these are the modules you can add to your kivy code while building apk:

> android apsw audiostream c_igraph cymunk django docutils ffmpeg gevent
>   greenlet hostpython igraph jpeg kivent kivy libevent libswift libxml2
>   libxslt lxml m2crypto msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy openssl
>   paramiko pil plyer png polygon psutil pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius
>   pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python sdl setuptools sqlalchemy
>   sqlite3 swift twisted txws wokkel zope

Let me know, if this satisfy your needs.